# multiple column crystal report with two section with different data

Tags: crystal-reports

i try to create table with two different details section

- in left column show list of data
- and in right column show different data

i try to use multiple column in details section but when use it can not set any controls in right side
in attached image [image]
i need to set data in right side but not accessible and when add new section added below i need to set this section beside left section 
like this 
[image]

Comment: In detail section use 2 sub reports side by side